# DB query optimization

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization

I am querying one column like

```
select * 
  from X1, X2, X3
 where X1.a = X2.a 
   and X2.b = X3.b 
   and X3.c IN ('c1a','c1b','c1c')
```

There will be around 10 such c1% value possible

An alternate query is:

```
select * 
  from X1, X2, X3
 where X1.a = X2.a 
   and X2.b = X3.b 
   and X3.c like 'c1%'
```

Here the table X3 has indexed on `c`

I understand the meaning of the two queries is different but in my use-case they will return the same results. I want to know which of the queries will be faster (and is it significant for instance in one case might an index not get used)?

Comment: Only _you_ can tell which will be faster. Benchmark it with your specific set-up and then you'll know.

Comment: If there is c1d, c1e, c1aaa and etc. then faster will be first query. But in first, place your tables are not related.

Comment: The execution plan will tell you the differences. And SQL*Plus' `autotrace` mode will tell you which one is *really* more efficient.

Answer (score 4):

> "which of the queries will be faster "

... is not a question we can answer.   Because you have not provided any useful information.  Query performance is largely a matter of two factors: volume and skew.

Volume means:

- how many rows in X1?
- how many rows in X2?
- how many rows in X3?

Skew means:

- how many rows in X1 match rows in X2?
- how many rows in X2 match rows in X3?
- how many rows in X3 have values in C which match 'c1%'?

That's why it is important to gather statistics, so that the database can understand the data distribution and devise the appropriate execution plan.

For instance, if X1 is a small table and matches hardly any rows in X2 and X2 matches hardly any rows in X3 then the access path is `X1 -> X2 -> X3' and the values of C are just filtering, so it doesn't matter how you specify them.

Whereas if X1 and X2 and large tables and match lots of rows, X3.C is likely to be the best access path, and so it really matters how you frame the query: which option is most likely to cause the optimizer to use an index (if that is the better plan) or not to use the index (if that is the better plan)?

I think it is more likely that the optimizer will choose to use an index for the `IN` over the `LIKE` operation.   But I wouldn't put a lot of money on it without knowing *way* more about your database than I know now.

> "is it significant for instance in one case might an index not get
>   used"

Of course it is.  Indexed reads can be the faster way of getting at the data we want.   But they can also be slower than a full table scan.  Again it's about data distribution: what percentage of the table's rows will be returned?  If it's more than 1-2% it's llikely that there are faster access paths than the index.  Although an index on `X3(c, b)` would offer good performance in this case (alas we can't always build an index to suit each individual query).